# Ejercicio de arboles en C#

Tags: c#

Quisiera ponerle funcionalidad a mi boton, quiero que apretando el boton se añada al arbol que tiene el nombre de tvwarbol.

¿Sería algo asi?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tvwarbol.Nodes.Add();
        }
```

Comment: ¿Y donde está tu clase `Arbol`?

Comment: se añada que cosa?

Comment: mira por favor [ask] <-ACA.. tu pregunta tiene que ser clara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   if (rbrama.Checked){

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text);

    }
    else if (rbhijo.Checked)
    {
        TreeNode objNode;
        objNode = treeView1.SelectedNode;
        objNode.Nodes.Add(textBox1.Text);

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ha de rellenar el formulario");
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias señor Trackless

Comment: Las respuestas deben tener una explicación de como ayuda a resolver el problema o que realiza el código. Revisar [answer].